# is HTML + Javascript the best option for web site design/implementation?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, web

We are in the middle of designing for our website and investigating on the techniques available. We run into to a few options - HTML, Javascript, JSP, ASP etc.

What we want to achieve is to have dynamic content on some pages that will pull data from backend web service, or push data to it. To do that, it seems that HTML + Javascript is actually good enough w/o involving JSP/ASP, is that a correct claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get information from a data base to a web browser without some sort of server side web application in between.  JSP/ASP fall under the category of "server side web application".  Javascript in the browser can ask a server for data and do something with it, but the server has to know how to read the database and deliver a decent response.

So you end up dividing the "website" in 2 parts:

1. Front-end: HTML, javascript, CSS, all running in the visitors browser
2. Back-end: delivers content and/or raw data to the web browser.

Most of todays dynamic websites involve a decent amount of code in both of these places.

So no, "it seems that HTML + Javascript is actually good enough w/o involving JSP/ASP" is not a correct claim, because you have no backend to serve the database content.

Comment: makes sense, agree with that you explained. we do have server side RESTful logic already build up to handle the request from client side, talk to databases and return the data to the client side.

Comment: In that case, you don't totally need the server render full pages of content in the traditional sense. If you have a robust API that serves JSON, you can use a JS framework like [Backbone JS](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) to build a client side app that pulls data from an API.  It's powerful architecture that lets you do a lot of really awesome things from a UI standpoint.  Checkout the [backbone examples](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#examples) for some real world use cases of this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need some server side ASP/JSP code to get dynamic content if you are going to use any sort of data store if your going to have any sort of user validation or single sing on. Though it is "possible" to have a "web app" written in HTML + JavaScript if you use a framework in like [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) to link you JavaScript data to you web services, assuming they are RESTful.

Backbone allows you to create a MVC / MVVM relationship between you data in you page and your UI. The Models can be set to pull their data from a RESTfull interface, eg you web service. After that you can update your data though the page and Backbone allows for easy update of that data back on the server, again through REST.

I have seen a tutorial where one page is the entire application and their Backbone enabled site just makes calls into the backed by REST.

There is also a derivation of Backbone called [Spine](http://spinejs.com/) that came from a developer at [Twitter](https://github.com/explore) but it seemed pretty apples to apples and more based on a love of CoffeeScript, but i'M stopping before i digress.

Comment: our server/web service side is purely RESTful and coded in java, any valid http request (based on our routing file) could be handled. in that case, would ASP/JSP is still needed on the server side?

Comment: You could set a collection in Backbone to pull its data from that RESTful server/web service. The library also lets you call .save() on your objects and it will post/put back to that same route you define. If its just pulling data out of the service and you believe you have a solution to access control you would not need ASP/JSP on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can have dynamic content without using JSP/ASP.

The Javascript XMLHttpRequest object is what allows you to do dynamic things.

Answer (score 0):

HTML+JavaScript will satisfy the client-side needs, but to actually pull data from a server, you need something running on the server side. This doesn't have to be JSP/ASP, but something needs to send the data from the server. It could be a web service as you mentioned, but that still runs on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the standard catchphrase is "graceful degradation."  When you write the whole site in an AJAX manner (with just HTML + Javascript), any browser which is unable to run Javascript will be unable to present your site well.  Such browsers do exist: old browsers, text-only browsers, NoScript extension, web spiders.

By coding with JSP/ASP/Your-favorite-server-side-scripting-environment, you leave open the possibility of graceful degradation.  Even if the browser is unable to run Javascript, your site can still remain navigable.

For the best experience, you'll probably want some sort of combination.  Javascript/AJAX for responsiveness, but capable of falling back to all server-side scripting for legacy support.

Of course, if legacy support is no concern, certainly a fully AJAX front end is reasonable.  Especially if you're in a situation where you need not worry about the one-domain-policy.  An intranet, a small public website expecting limited clientele might be reasonable places for such a site.